# I'm trying to alert elements from an HTML form using JavaScript but not getting anything

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to alert elements from a HTML form using JavaScript. I've followed most of the questions and tried following the same code, but I can't get it to alert. Please help me. Thanks.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Registration </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="registration">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Your details</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <label for="namefirst">First Name</label>
                    <input id="namefirst" class="details" name="nameFirst" placeholder="John" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value=""/>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <label for="namelast">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="namelast" class="details" name="namelast" placeholder ="Dickens" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input id="username" class="details" name="username" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">e-mail</label>
                    <input id="email" class="details" name="email" placeholder="xxxx@xmail.com" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value=""/>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
                <p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

                <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

                <p id="demo"></p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
    myfunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
    var text = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            text += x[i].value + " ";
    }
    alert(text);
    }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the console of the browser?

Answer (score 4):

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
var text = "";
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        text += x[i].value + " ";
}
alert(text);
}
```

You did not declare you function correctly . And `myfunction` is not `myFunction`

Answer (score 2):

Problems

- The defined function as `myfunction` however using `myFunction`
- The default behaviour of `button` element is to submit form, You need to set `type` attribute as `button`.

*Code*, change the HTML to

```
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">Try it</button>
```

```js
  function myfunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
    var text = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      text += x[i].value + " ";
    }
    alert(text);
  }
```

```html
<form id="registration">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your details</legend>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="namefirst">First Name</label>
        <input id="namefirst" class="details" name="nameFirst" placeholder="John" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value="" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="namelast">Last Name</label>
        <input id="namelast" class="details" name="namelast" placeholder="Dickens" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value="" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" class="details" name="username" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value="" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="email">e-mail</label>
        <input id="email" class="details" name="email" placeholder="xxxx@xmail.com" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value="" />
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Registration </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="registration">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Your details</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <label for="namefirst">First Name</label>
                    <input id="namefirst" class="details" name="nameFirst" placeholder="John" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value=""/>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <label for="namelast">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="namelast" class="details" name="namelast" placeholder ="Dickens" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input id="username" class="details" name="username" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">e-mail</label>
                    <input id="email" class="details" name="email" placeholder="xxxx@xmail.com" required="" autofocus="" type="text" value=""/>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
                <p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

                <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Try it</button>

                <p id="demo"></p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
    var text = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            text += x[i].value + " ";
            
    }
    alert(text);
    }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```